# cant deploy my contract and getting same error

Tags: solidity, blockchain, smart-contract

I am new to solidity . I am trying to learn solidity following a course . I trying to deploy my contract . I am getting same error again and again . I have tried some solution with same title I found here . It seems not work .

The error says :

> Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

I am stuck with this error for so long .

My sepolia test network balance is 0.0022 ,do I have to get more ?

here is deploy.js file

```
const HDWalletProvider=require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');

const Web3=require('web3');

const{interface,bytecode}=require('./compile');

const provider=new HDWalletProvider(
    //i put my account prase here
);

const web3 =new Web3(provider);

const deploy= async()=>{

    const accounts=await web3.eth.getAccounts(); 

    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account',accounts[0]);

   const result= await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({data:'0x0'+bytecode,arguments:['Hi,there']})
    .send({gas:"1000000",from:accounts[0]});

    console.log('Contract deployed to',result.options.address);

};
deploy();
```

my main contract :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.26;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    constructor(string memory intialmsg) public{
        message = intialmsg;
    }

    function setmessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

My compile.js file

```
const path= require('path');
const fs= require('fs');

const solc=require('solc');



const inboxPath=path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','Inbox.sol');

const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf-8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Inbox'];
console.log( solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Inbox']);
```

My package.js file

```
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "^4.6.0",
    "solc": "^0.4.26",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot .Dont want to give up on my journey .

Comment: Try to get some Sepolia ETH from the faucet.

https://sepolia-faucet.pk910.de/

Answer (score 0):

I also think that you don't have enough money for gas. You can use Remix Ide -> import your contract and inject Metamask and click to deploy to see how much a contract will cost to deploy.

Comment: I have 2eth now in my test network , the error says

Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.

Comment: try to increase gas from here : .send({gas:"1000000",from:accounts[0]});

Comment: !!! You also posted your seed phrase. Everyone now have access to your fund. You should never post seed phrases, not even from testnets. Move your funds to another wallet

Comment: i tried to  increase gas from here ,i put different values ,it seems not to work

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70664908/web3-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-out-of-gas

Answer (score 0):

Using string in a constructor needs more gas than usual, also you set gas in your arguments , remove gas and try again , if it doesn't work set gas limit and gas price in arguments

Comment: .send({ gas: "10000000",gasLimit:"2000000",gasPrice:"2000", from: accounts[0] });
i tried tthis ,still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I could easily migrate with minimal settings in my ganache

[image]

[image]

**Inbox_migration.js**

```
const Inbox = artifacts.require("Inbox");

module.exports = function (deployer, network, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(Inbox, "Hello World");
};
```

**truffle-config.js**

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

const fs = require('fs');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  contracts_build_directory: "./build/contracts",
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `http://127.0.0.1:7545`),
      network_id: 5777,       // Ropsten's id
      gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
      confirmations: 0,    // # of confirmations to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
      timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    },
  },


  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters, etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.7",      // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      docker: false,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
       optimizer: {
         enabled: false,
         runs: 200
       },
       evmVersion: "byzantium"
      }
    }
  },
};
```